# Run mathematica file without GUI

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I use SSH mode to remote access the computer with Linux system.

If use GUI, I need to compile "CRN.m" written by mathematica first, then compile the file "lulu.nb" to get the final results.

My question is how to use terminal command to run the mathematica code, which has two steps---compiling "CRN.m" first and then "lulu.nb".

I try the math -run, it says cannot open the CRN.m since it is not a mathematica notebook.

Comment: Notebooks are interpreted by the front end, not the kernel. Try saving lulu.nb as lulu.wl from the GUI menu File / Save As... and then try `wolframscript -file lulu.wl`. Check the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html).

Comment: the terminal reports no wolframscript command

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: It is the version 10.2